# Alt+number does not switch terminal windows but gives me an unwanted Bash function instead

Tags: bash, 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, keyboard-layout

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.1. I want <kbd>Alt</kbd>+n (where n=1,2,3,4...) to switch between the respective terminal windows to speed up my workflow. However, when I do this in terminal, I get an output: (arg: n), where n is the number I press. My keyboard shortcuts are set so that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+n switches to the nth window, but I don't see this effect working.

I understand that this has something to do with readline arguments but this is a function I currently don't need, and so I want to remap this to switch between terminal windows somehow.

Thanks for your help folks!

P.S. I should mention this also has an effect on pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd>, I get: ~3 with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and ;~3 with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>.

Comment: if you use tabs instead of multiple windows it works fine. use ctrl+shit+t to open a new tab

Comment: This is a solution of sorts, thank you, I wasn't aware that you could even open tabs. However, I would still like to be able to switch between terminal windows as I like to have a few in sight at once. Thanks so far though!

Comment: yea, that's why I didn't put it as an answer.... also, you can cycle windows of the same application with alt+` (that's the key above tab)... again not the solution you are looking for, but better than nothing

Comment: FYI the behavior you are observing is related to the shell's editing mode: see for example [Shell vi mode prints (arg: repetition): How to remove it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125092/shell-vi-mode-prints-arg-repetition-how-to-remove-it)

Comment: If you are using fedora 32 goto -> preferences in your terminal and uncheck mnemonics options make you change your tabs.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issue while switching between terminal tabs using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + number on Ubuntu 20.04. The issue gets resolved by disabling mnemonics from terminal preferences settings (Preferences --> General --> Untick "Enable mnemonics").

[image: Disable mnemonics]

Comment: Answer still useful in Ubuntu 21.10